# Rename python click argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, python-click

I have this chunk of code:

```
import click

@click.option('--delete_thing', help="Delete some things columns.", default=False)
def cmd_do_this(delete_thing=False):
    print "I deleted the thing."
```

I would like to rename the option variable in `--delete-thing`. But python does not allow dashes in variable names. Is there a way to write this kind of code?

```
import click

@click.option('--delete-thing', help="Delete some things columns.", default=False, store_variable=delete_thing)
    def cmd_do_this(delete_thing=False):
        print "I deleted the thing."
```

So `delete_thing` will be set to the value of `delete-thing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, click will intelligently map intra-option commandline hyphens to underscores so your code should work as-is. This is used in the click documentation, e.g., in the [Choice example](http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#choice-options). If --delete-thing is intended to be a boolean option, you may also want to make it a [boolean argument](http://click.pocoo.org/5/options/#boolean-flags).

Comment: And it's true! Though I understood the take home message, your second link probably points to the wrong page.

Answer (score 6):

As gbe's answer says, `click` will automatically convert `-` in the cli parameters to `_` for the python function parameters.

But you can also explicitly name the python variable to whatever you want. In this example, it converts `--delete-thing` to `new_var_name`:

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--delete-thing', 'new_var_name')

def cmd_do_this(new_var_name):
    print(f"I deleted the thing: {new_var_name}")
```